# How to replace "-" with " -" only when it's not preceded by "e"?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I imagine I should use Regex for that but I still scratch my head a lot about it (and the only similar question I found wasn't exactly my case) so I decided to ask for help. This is the input and expected output:

```
Input:  "c-0.68219,-0.0478 -1.01455-0.0441 0.9e-4,0.43212"
Output: "c -0.68219,-0.0478 -1.01455 -0.0441 0.9e-4,0.43212"
```

Basically I need either commas or spaces as value separators, but I can't break the exponential index (`e‑4`). Maybe do two successive replacements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been some time for me, but you should be able to use something like this:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"([^e\s])-(\d)");
rx.Replace(input, "$1 -$2");
```

Edit: This will add a space in front even if there's a comma. Any reason not doing this?

Comment: Excellent! Worked first try, even on an edge case like "0.0661-10e-4". leoinfo's answer is also correct, you just beat him by a couple mins. I'm not only ultra-thankful (you saved my day!) but also extremely humbled by you guys speed. All thumbs up! :)

Comment: no need for any thumbs to be up. All we need is your Index finger to click on the Tick next to the answer To mark this as a correct Answer....

Comment: @HaLaBi I tried but it didn't work at first, done now. Anyways, I found a little shortcoming with the code that something like "1.4-4-1.9" wouldn't properly parse (second hyphen wouldn't split) so I had to run the regex twice. No idea if there's a better way. Also, simply splitting any two digits seemed to do the job just fine, like so: `  Regex rx = new Regex(@"([\d])-(\d)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  coords = rx.Replace(coords, "$1 -$2");
  coords = rx.Replace(coords, "$1 -$2");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below also

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(MyString, "([^0-9,e,., ,e-])", "$1 ",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```